# If Keras CNN model is trained on 28x28 images, how can I accurately predict images of higher resolutions?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to train an OCR model using CNN's and have an EMNIST dataset with letters for training the model to recognize handwritten English letters.

My question is, if I train the CNN with input image shape of 28x28, then during prediction, do I have to resize the image to be predicted to 28x28, or something else?

I am asking this because I originally trained a CNN model on 90x90 images and I am achieving a decent 93.4% accuracy on them. But when I resize similar images to 90x90 for prediction, the model predicts way out of the correct label.

I don't know what I am missing here, so all your guidance is duly appreciated.

Comment: Does 93.4% accuracy refers to test samples or train samples. If it refers to the former how similar are your images to the training ones? Can you provide some examples?

Comment: Yes you have to resize your images to be 28x28 for prediction. What is the starting resolution when you resized to 90x90 for prediction? Did you use the same images as in the test set, as in the training set, or images never put into the model to do your predictions to compare to the accuracy?